# Перегрузка метода в PHP ООП

Tags: ооп, php

Единомышленники есть?

Нужно, что бы метод А перегружался другими аргументами. И это вообще реально. Пол гугла перекопал - всякая ерунда написана, ей богу. Вот кусок кода:

```
<?php
class A
{
    var $ClassName;

    function A($name)
    {
        $this->ClassName = $name;
        echo "Init class A param {$name}";
    }

    function A()
    {
        echo "Init class A is not param";
    }

    function _get()
    {
        echo $this->ClassName;
    }
}

$object = new A();
$object->_get();
?>
```

Вариант вот такой не предлагать:

```
function A($name=NULL) { 
    $this->ClassName=$name; 
    echo "Init class A param {$name}"; 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Сделать несколько функций с одинаковыми названиями и разными аргументами в PHP - **нельзя**

Но можно извратится и написать чтото  типа:

```
class A {
    public function myMethod()
    {
        $cnt = func_num_args();
        $cb = 'myMethod'.$cnt;
        if ($cnt == 0) {
            return $this->myMethod0();
        } elseif ($cnt == 1) {
            return $this->myMethod1(func_get_arg(0));
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Method not implemented');
        }

    }

    protected function myMethod0()
    {
        // do somethings
    }

    protected function myMethod1($arg1)
    {
        // do somethings
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class B extends A{
    function A($name = ''){
        //...
        parent::A('somename');
    }
}

$object = new B();
//...
```

Только я не уверен насчет того, что случится, если A() - конструктор класса. Плюс, могут возникнуть проблемы с не-public свойствами и методами.